# android how to set particular item position for viewpager when onBackPressed()?

Tags: java, android

// Here is the adapter for viewpager

```
 public void setupViewPager(){
    pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                pageAdapter.addFragment(FragmentDesigns.newInstance(), "INDIAFILINGS");
                icfo = ICFO.newInstance();
                pageAdapter.addFragment(icfo, "iCFO PLATFORM");
                viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    // here code to set particular item in viewpager
    int pageRedirect;
                pageRedirect=CommonClass.getPageRedirect();
                try {
                    if(pageRedirect!=0){
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
```

I am implementing `viewpager` with two fragments.In second Fragment i have list of data if user selects any item from a list it will redirect to another activity.If user does `onbackPress` in activity i want to set `viewpager` second fragment as a current fragment

Note:The issue is when i do `onbackPress` the application is getting close

Comment: How you are calling second activity? Add code here.

Answer (score 0):

override the onBackPressed method in your second activity so that system default behaviour does not happen

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

   Intent firstintent = new Intent(context,Firstactivity.class);

firstintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

   startActivity(firstintent);

}
```

This will open the first activity, close the second activity and deliver the result in the onNewIntent of the first activity

In your first activity override onNewIntent so that the back press result is found

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    yourvp.setCurrentItem(positionyouneed);
}
```

This should do the trick for you

Comment: i want to set viewpager currentitem when user backpressed in second activity

Comment: does the second acitivity need to close? Also since your application is closing i believe that before launching the 2nd activity, you are calling finish() on the first one

Comment: also i had removed finish in first one while redirecting to second page

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(secondViewpagerItemPostion,false);
        }else{
             super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
```

Comment: put some sort of an explanation for him buddy

Comment: Yes sure,but i am edttting my answer right now...thanks

Comment: i have two different activities the code which u have given for first activity

Comment: @Vishali i think u need to explain what you need better in the question then, because from your question, this is the answer both of us came up with

Comment: When user press back in second activity ,then in first activity ,there is one method onRestart() .You can set your second viewPager item as default

Comment: @Kabir that will cause the activity to go to the 2nd fragment when the user presses home button and opens the app again... OP only wants it to happen on back press from 2nd activity

Comment: Then one way is that:in second activity ,when user press backButton,then send LocaBroadcast to first activity and set your default fragment in onReceive method

Comment: too complicated man, just use intent flags like my answer... why go through the whole broadcase process :D

Answer (score 0):

Store your current position of view pager in sharepref and check it if not null then viewpager.setCurrentItem(shareprefPosition);

Comment: i am storing value in commonclass when backpress in second activity later i am getting the value in first activity to set viewpager currentitem position

Comment: Have you tried with onResume? You can put it onresume method.  int pageRedirect;
                pageRedirect=CommonClass.getPageRedirect();
                try {
                    if(pageRedirect!=0){
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }